# How to construct a matrix in Julia sequentially?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I need to construct a matrix in Julia by appending rows. The idea is this:

```
mat = []     # initialize empty mat
for i = 1:5
    x, y = f(i), g(i)    # here f and g are previously defined functions
    mat = [mat; [x y]]
end
```

This doesn't work, I get an error:

> ERROR: DimensionMismatch("mismatch in dimension 2 (expected 2 got 1)")

in the line where I try to append to `mat`. I am new to Julia. How can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: If you don't know how many rows you need to add up front (and hence cannot pre-allocate), perhaps a `Vector{Vector{T}}` would be more efficient? You can dynamically add elements to each inner vector using `push!` with very little performance overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial `mat = []` creates a 1-dim array. The proper way to initialize would be `mat = reshape([],0,2)`. Perhaps typing the array is also recommended. For example, `mat = Array{Float64}(0,2)`.

Concatenating rows this way is costly because of the column-first ordering of arrays in memory used by Julia. Consider defining the full array and assigning elements in the loop. Possibly `mat = Array{Float64}(5,2)`.

Also, a commenter suggested `Matrix(0,2)` which is another method to initialize a 0x2 matrix.